# Swift NSMutableDictionary removeobject

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMutableDictionary I initiated like this

```
    var data = NSMutableDictionary()
```

later I am trying to remove the value because I want to move every value up one key. This is the code I am doing

```
let buttonRow = sender.tag
    let setCount = buttonRow + 1
    var keyedPath: String = NSString(format: "Set%d", setCount) as String
    let value: AnyObject? = data.valueForKey(keyedPath)
    var goodSetsCount: String = NSString(format: "Set%d", goodSets.count) as String
    goodSets.setValue(value, forKey: goodSetsCount)
    //data.setValue("Hello", forKey: keyedPath)
    //data.removeObjectForKey(keyedPath)
```

On both of the lines that are commented out I get this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

If you can help me find the bug or a way to remove objects and move them up the dictionary it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to remove objects from a different dictionary that isn't mutable (an `NSDictionary`). Find it and initialize it as mutable.

Comment: Use mutableCopy when you are setting data

Comment: Why don't you just use an array?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not using and array because its a dictionary and then all the values are another dictionary

Comment: @rebello95  This is the line of code I used to initialize it                                      data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(returnData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as! NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 1):

By default, `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` returns immutable containers.  You need to specify the option `NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers` in order to retrieve a mutable containers.  In fact, in Swift 1.2 your assignment

```
data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(returnData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as! NSMutableDictionary
```

should throw a run time exception because you are using a forced downcast to NSMutableDictionary that will fail, although I am not sure if this is enforced with Cocoa classes.

If you change the line to

```
data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(returnData, options: .MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as! NSMutableDictionary
```

your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @Pauwlw11 you are trying to modify immutable dictionary object. Apart from that your code could be clear if you use with Swift constructs rather than just plainly translating it from Objective-C.

```
var data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(returnData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as NSMutableDictionary
```

In button click handler:

```
let setCount = 1
var keyedPath = "Set\(setCount)"
let value = data[keyedPath]

var goodSetsCount = "Set\(setCount)"
data[keyedPath] = "Hello"
data.removeObjectForKey(keyedPath)
```